# How do I select text inside a <span> that is inside an HTMLCollection of links <a> using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to scrape some data for a fun personal project, and I'm new to JS. I'm trying to get an array of team names from an HTMLCollection (using Chrome Dev Tools). If there's an easier way I'm open to it. So far:

```
let vMidCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("v-mid");
vMidCollection[0]
```

[image]

QUESTION: Each `<a></a>` contains a `<span></span>` but I need an array of team names (underlined). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll#dataset_selector_attribute_selectors)

```js
const teamNames = [...document.querySelectorAll('.v-mid span.teamName')].map(e => e.textContent)

console.log(teamNames)
```

```html
<a class="v-mid">
  <div>
    <span class="teamName">Test </span>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="v-mid">
  <div>
    <span class="teamName">Test 1</span>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="v-mid">
  <div>
    <span class="teamName">Test 2</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```js
let vMidCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("v-mid");
team_names = []
Array.from(vMidCollection).forEach( (elem) => {team_names.push(elem.querySelector(".teamName").innerText)})

console.log(team_names)
```

```html
<a class="v-mid">
  <div>
    Stuff
  </div>
  <span class="teamName">Tam 1 </span>
</a>
<a class="v-mid">
  <div>
    Stuff
  </div>
  <span class="teamName">Team 2</span>
</a>
<a class="v-mid">
  <div>
    Stuff
  </div>
  <span class="teamName">Team3</span>
</a>
```

It finds every element inside `vMidCollection` that has `class="teamname"` and appends it text to `team_names`

Comment: That's similar to what I originally tried, but I get this:
`VM131724:1 Uncaught TypeError: vMidCollection.forEach is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:16
(anonymous) @ VM131724:1`

Is this particular website blocking me from accessing their data possibly?

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it beforhand. Fixed it.